# Error when call WriteProcessMemory using inline asm

Tags: c++, assembly, inline

I want to call **WriteProcessMemory** in my **c++** application (msvc visual studio) using **__asm** block.

```
#include <windows.h>    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>       
const char* TextVar = "loon";
int main(){
 auto addrof = std::addressof(TextVar);
 unsigned int address = (unsigned int)addrof;
 HANDLE ProcessHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
 //WriteProcessMemory( HANDLE hProcess, LPVOID lpBaseAddress, LPCVOID lpBuffer, SIZE_T nSize, SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesWritten );
 __asm 
 {
   xor  eax, eax           // clear eax
   push 0x74736554         // push "Test"
   mov  eax, esp           // mov "Test" to eax

   push 0x0                // lpNumberOfBytesWritten
   push 0x4                // nSize [strlen("Test") = 4]
   push eax                // lpBuffer - "Test"
   push [address]          // lpBaseAddress - address of TextVar
   push ProcessHandle      // hProcess - Handle of current process
   call WriteProcessMemory

   push DWORD PTR[TextVar]
   call printf             //Print TextVar
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But i get this:

**An exception was thrown at the address 0x753F288E (ucrtbase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: read access violation at 0x74736554.**

//0x753F288E - printf address

//0x74736554 - my text - [Test]

What am I doing wrong? As I understand it, WPM writes the text as an address in TextVar. But how to fix that?

**P.S - I do not want to use local variables in c++ as a buffer for WPM.**

Comment: What happens if you remove the code for WPM and just do the printf?  Also, WPM takes 5 parameters and you are pushing 6 values?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd With printf it works. About 6 values - you're not right, it use only 5 parameters, which i push.

Answer (score -2):

I believe Windows APIs use Pascal calling conventions, pushing parameters to the stack from left to right. You seem to be doing the opposite, using C calling conventions.

Comment: They worked by accident. They probably are doing something else than what you intended. The likely reason is the write protection which was triggered by this call but not other.

Comment: When I saw that I didn’t crash, I thought that everything worked, but in fact it doesn’t write anything.....

Comment: It doesn't crash because of arguments, i check it. It crash because WPM write hex string in address format, not string..hmm